# Why is this less specific conditional different from an explicit one?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

```
if ($args->theme_location === 'header' || $args->theme_location === 'uia') {
```

evaluates to: (bool) false  (bool) True

```
if ($args->theme_location === 'header' || 'uia') {
```

evaluates to: (bool) false  (bool) True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition will always be true. The reason is the different priorities of the operators. === works first, || works after. Therefore $ args-> theme_location === 'header' || 'uia' is always true
This is the same as

```
($args->theme_location === 'header') || 'uia'
```